# Javascript identifying enabled drop down select type

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a form with multiple types of entry fields with some complicated validation that disables/enables various input types based on what the user enters or selects.  I am using JS to check the different enabled input types and if they are empty it keeps a running total.  Everytime an enabled input is modified the CheckForm function runs.

However, the problem that I am having is identifying which drop down select types are enabled, and if empty then they need to be counted in the alt_count variable.  If you look at the code below please note that check boxes and normal text entry types are working fine, it is only a problem with the select-one type.

Code:

```
function CheckForm() {
    var alt_count = 0;
    var field_list = '';

    $('tr#BaseTab td input:not(:button):not(:disabled), tr#BaseTab td select:not(:disabled)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
            var temp_obj = $(this);
            var temp_name = $(this).attr('name');
            if ($('input[name=' + temp_name + ']:checked').length === 0) {
                alt_count += 1;
            }
        } else if ($(this).attr('type') === 'select-one') {
            if ($(this).attr("selectedIndex") === 0) {
                alt_count += 1;
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                alt_count += 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Is there form code to look at? You've totally confirmed that your select are getting disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` element will not actually have the attribute `type="select-one"`.  However, the DOM element will have a `.type` property that allows you to check if you are dealing with a `select-one` or a `select-multiple`. So, instead of checking the 'type' attribute, check the property like this:

```
else if ($(this)[0].type === 'select-one') {
```